# QML ListView inside Repeater

Tags: c++, qt, listview, qml, repeater

How can I assign different models to a `ListView`, which is inside a `Repeater`?
I did a sketch (my actual project is much larger):

```
Column {
    Repeater {
        model: ["Line1","Line2","Line3","Line4"]
        Rectangle {
            ListView {
                model: ???
                delegate: Rectangle {
                    Text {
                        text: somemodelproperty
                    }                
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Currently, I am solving the idea by copy-pasting 10 Rectangles, each containing a `ListView`. In C++, I have implemented 10 `QList<QObject*>`, and each list is "bounded" to a `ListView` by doing

```
QQmlContext * example = engine.rootContext();
example->setContextProperty(modelname,QVariant::fromValue(listobject));
```

I am pretty sure there is a more intelligent way to do this, but I have just started working with QML a few days ago, and can't figure out a solution.

Answer (score 2):

There is the catch, you can't use an `id` as a value for a list element, nor can you nest a list model inside a list element, at least not directly.

You can however populate it like this:

```
Item {
    id: models
    ListModel {/*...*/}
    ListModel {/*...*/}
    //...
}

ListModel {
    id: outerModel
}

function set() {
    for (var i = 0; i < models.data.length; ++i) {
        outerModel.append({"model": models.data[i] /* and other stuff */})
    }
}
```

Or if you prefer using your C++ data, you can add a `QObject*` "model" property to each of the elements in the list and set it with a function, either as in the example above or with the `id`s for the inner models you specify.

On a second thought, you might want to use another name instead of "model" because I can't imagine QML will be happy about something like `model: model`

**Update**: You could try doing something like this (assuming your 10 models are exposed as `m1` - `m10` in QML)

```
property var subModels: [m1, m2, ... m10]
```

Then for the `ListView` inside the repeater delegate you can:

```
ListView {
    model: subModels[index]
    // ...
}
```

Then assuming you have 10 elements in the repeater, the model for each list view will be selected from the array with the appropriate element index.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your answer a little? I want to use my C++ data, which are lists of `QObject*`s. What exactly should I put in the `ListModel`s from the `Item` ? And where does all that fit in the `repeater`? Thanks.

Comment: +1, just alias `model` with a propery with another name, and bind to that (i.e. in cases, when you can't rename it)

Answer (score 1):

Declare model for repeater instead of using array of strings. You can use ListModel for that purposes. You can also add to ListModels element, ListElement, any properties you want. Declare something like following:

```
ListModel { 
   id: repeaterModel
   ListElement { title: "Line1"; model: modelForFirstElement; }
   ListElement { title: "Line2"; model: modelForSecondElement; }
   // ...
}
```

Then assign it to your Repeater's model property

```
Repeater {
   id: repeater
   model: repeaterModel
// ...
```

Then you will be able to access to model for your ListView by just calling model's model property, like this (assuming that you have assigned id "repeater" for your Repeater element):

```
ListView {
   model: repeater.model.model
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I encountered a problem: when using the suggested ListModel, I get `"ListElement: cannot use script for property value"` because of the model in the ListElement, apparently.

Comment: Ok, it seems to be that ListElement can handle only simple values, like strings or integer values. So, do not assign/declare pointer to model or model itself inside it. Instead, assign string value, like `model: "modelForFirstElement"` etc. Then, declare property in repeaterModel, like: `property var subModels: { "modelForFirstElement": modelForFirstElement, "modelForSecondElement": modelForSecondElement }` etc. Then change `model: repeater.model.model` to `repeater.model.subModels[ repeater.model.model ]`. Comment if it works, please - I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, and I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined` at `repeater.model.subModels[ repeater.model.model ]` . I have double-checked the code to make sure the `id`s were all correctly written. It's unfortunate that Qt doesn't support having models inside ListElements, because that would be the most logical solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

For the model, consider an array that has a sub-array nested within. To differentiate since both the outer `Repeater` and the inner `ListView` have a different instance of `modelData` consider copying the outer `modelData` to a property named `outerModelData`.

In the following example, I refactor out `Column`-`Repeater`-`ListView` and replaced it with `ListView`-`ListView`. Both patterns achieve the same thing but the latter does it shorter.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls

Page {
    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: [
            {la:"English",v:["one","two","three"]},
            {la:"Mandarin",v:["yi","er","san"]},
            {la:"French",v:["un","duex","trois"]},
            {la:"German",v:["eins","zwei","drei"]},
            {la:"Indonesian",v:["satu","dua","tiga"]},
        ]
        delegate: ListView {
            property var outerModelData: modelData
            width: 120
            height: childrenRect.height
            header: Text { text: outerModelData.la }
            model: outerModelData.v
            delegate: Frame {
                width: 100
                Text { text: modelData }                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAAC8nicbZFNT8MwDIbv/RVRz1M1OOYKDCExiSHEZdrBak1r0SaV464bU/87CS0dLfUhH8776LUdqmrLonayayj9jGhyTe6sEbali6IXyFFdIuXjmZy8E7bDNQSYtLDskg8qS61qYDQyPlY2Q5/dj4kQlxJ0/GDyklwRr456H1uD8SqW1oa1YMT40K3+M1swGTCZHjqTVyP7xYFZBja+mHTwaDwWZw2eggdbcsvII3IFgwOScV791WKwythvi8yTyXwHjn45B9L8mEHwohwm2GE8+dlgDoJ6aa4harY1spzVEVjZRpC3YaD3IKD72YbjBGkpk0Krm9v1JF0g5YVolRZU+kbMK6aS9MmZDjJkrd7wJOqixG965pyUoLoJNPzyTHacaK69bhgqnDX6t/L1+t/TpJqxb9XNdRPwWmN/6qLuG7/jyvE=)